# What is the best practice to add tuples to a set?

Tags: python, set, addition, data-consistency

Consider this example:

```
In [44]: exl_set = set(a.node)
In [45]: exl_set 
Out[45]: set(['1456030', '-9221969'])
In [46]: exl_set.add(b.node)
In [47]: exl_set
Out[47]: set(['1456030', ('-9227619', '1458170'), '-9221969'])
```

What is the best way to add `tuples` of length 2 to a `set` without breaking them apart with the first `add`? The result should look like this:

```
Out[48]: set([ ('-9221969','1456030'),('-9227619', '1458170')])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your initial node in list or tuple:

```
exl_set = set([a.node])
```

to not have it interpreted as a sequence of values.

The `set()` constructor interprets the argument as an iterable and will take all values in that iterable to add to the set; from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> *class* **`set([iterable])`**:
>   Return a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from `iterable`.

Demo:

```
>>> node = ('1456030', '-9221969')
>>> set(node)
set(['1456030', '-9221969'])
>>> set([node])
set([('1456030', '-9221969')])
>>> len(set([node]))
1
```

Alternatively, create an empty set and use `set.add()` exclusively:

```
exl_set = set()
exl_set.add(a.node)
exl_set.add(b.node)
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, of course I thought about this. But it means I have to keep track of my iteration. Thought there might be a better way to go...

Comment: The last piece of information is what I was looking for! Great, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: @LarsVegas: out-of-band comment: the Careers URL on your profile is a private edit URL for your profile, visible to you only. You want to use the [public URL for your profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199672) instead.

Comment: btw, if you have a choice between creating a list, or a tuple - choose the tuple i.e. instead of `set([node])`, use `set((node))`. it's about 25% faster - 231 ns vs. 304 ns for this particular case, per addition.

Comment: One small but significant point about @CorleyBrigman 's comment above: a trailing comma is needed for python to interpret the parens as a single element tuple, i.e.: `set((node,))`

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the set, the argument is treated as an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set), not as a single item. You can do it like that:

```
    >>>node = (1, 3)
    >>>node_set = set([node,]) #  initialize a set with a single ilement
    >>>node_set
    set([(1, 3)])
```

or alternatively:

```
    >>>node = (1, 4)
    >>>node_set = set()  # initialize an empty set
    >>>node_set.add(node)  # add a single element
    >>>node_set
    set([(1, 4)])
```

Answer (score 1):

To update this answer for other time travellers, another method is to use a set literal, which saves on the unnecessary wrap/unwrap process of the previous answers:

```py
node = (1, 2)
n_set = {node}
n_set
```

> Out[17]: {(1, 2)}